# yii2: installation fancybox extension with composer

Tags: fancybox, installation, composer-php, yii-extensions, yii2

I don't really understand how install fancybox with composer.

I followed these instructions: https://github.com/newerton/yii2-fancybox

I always get the same errors:

> *Problem 1
>       - The requested package newerton/yii2-fancybox could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.*

or

> *Could not find package * at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check th   e package spelling or your minimum-stability*

Answer (score 0):

Since this package do not have any stable release, you should modify your stability settings in composer.json, e.g. :

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links